# Error code C2679

Tags: c++

Following a guide and I'm getting a c3867 error (binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'void') but I'm not entirely sure why or how I'd fix it.

I'm trying to use Composition to call the birthday.printDate function through the people class, I literally started CPP yesterday, so I apologise for the mistakes that I've made (the class names don't start capitalised etc).

Here's my code:

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream> 
#include "birthday.h"
#include "people.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {

    birthday birthObj(4, 1, 1998);
    people User("User", birthObj);

    User.printInfo();

    system("pause");
}
```

people.h

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include "birthday.h"
using namespace std;


class people
{

public:
    people(string x, birthday bo);
    void printInfo();

private:
    string name;
    birthday dateOfBirth;

};
```

people.cpp

```
#include "people.h"
#include "birthday.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;



people::people(string x, birthday bo)
    :name(x), dateOfBirth(bo)
{
}

void people::printInfo() {
    cout << name << " was born on " << dateOfBirth.printDate() << endl;

}
```

birthday.h

```
#pragma once
class birthday
{
public:
    birthday(int d, int m, int y);
    void printDate();
private:
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
};
```

birthday.cpp

```
#include <iostream> 
#include "birthday.h"
using namespace std;


birthday::birthday(int d, int m, int y){
    day = d;
    month = m;
    year = y;

}

void birthday::printDate() {
    cout << day << "/" << month << "/" << year << endl;

}
```

I followed the advice given to the best of my ability but I still don't understand why I can't call printDate.

Comment: You made a typo. Look how you are calling (or not) `printDate`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see the type that I made? 
the printDate is a function within birthday.cpp, how am I correctly meant to call it then?

Comment: Actually, you made one and maybe even two. `printDate` is a function, if you want to call it, you have to use the parentheses. Also, it doesn't return anything, so you can't output it.

Comment: I tried with parentheses and it I still couldn't compile it, and I'm not sure what you mean I can't output to it? Sorry, I'm really new with this. The issue is definitely with the printDate function I'm just not sure I've wrapped my head around how it works.

Comment: Rakete1111 said "you can't output it", not "*to* it".

Comment: I still don't understand either way. why can't I output it? it should excute the code ""cout << day << "/" << month << "/" << year << endl;", no?

Comment: @melpomene Is there really a difference? For OP: it doesn't return anything. `void` is nothing basically. Just call it: `dateOfBirth.printDate();`.